# как в vscode обернуть текст и сделать все строки списком?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

При форматировании текста необходимо автоматизировать процесс вёрстки `.md` - файла.

**Пример:**
В файле `README.md` имеется *n-строк*, которые должны стать списком.

> Есть ли возможность выделить все строки и нажать комбинацию кнопок, чтобы получить автоматически-созданный список? (Неужели каждую строку минусом отмечать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделяете блок текста, нажимаете Alt+Shift+i - в конце каждой строки появляется курсор, нажимаете Home - теперь курсоры в начале строк и затем ставите минус. Итог - в начале каждой строки появляется минус и не надо править каждую строку отдельно.

Comment: Выделил, нажал <Alt>+<i> но ничего не роизошло( ожидал появление курсора в конце строки)

Comment: это потому что я наврал, надо Alt+Shift+i нажимать, извините за неточность. Ответ поправил

Comment: Этот вариант тоже не рабочий (

Answer (score 0):

**Создание ненумерованного списка из определённых строк**

1. Выделить необходимые строки.
2. Нажать сочетание кнопок: <`Ctrl`> + <`Shift`> + <`L`>
3. Появившийся курсор на всех строках переместить в начало строки, нажав <`Home`>
4. Нажать <`-`> (минус) потом <`Break Space`> (пробел)

Список готов.